# How to make work bindaddress in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have several failover IPs that are well configured (they work with wget or curl), and I would like to bind them when I use Scrapy, so I use the bindaddress key to achieve this, but the public IP is still the main IP.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import random
#https://ipinfo.io/ip

class SpiderTest(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "failover"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://ipinfo.io/ip'
        bind_addresses = ['BBB.BBB.BBB.BBX', 'BBB.BBB.BBB.BBY', 'BBB.BBB.BBB.BBZ']
        bind_address = random.choice(bind_addresses)
        print('Bind :      ' + bind_address)
        request = scrapy.Request(url=url,
                             callback=self.test,
                             meta={"bindaddress": (bind_address, 0)})
        yield request

    def test(self, response):
        html = response.body
        print('Public IP : ' + html.decode('ascii'))
```

Dis I miss something elsewhere ?

EDIT, an excerpt from ip addr :

```
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA/32 brd AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet BBB.BBB.BBB.BBX/32 brd BBB.BBB.BBB.BBX scope global ens3:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet BBB.BBB.BBB.BBY/32 brd BBB.BBB.BBB.BBY scope global ens3:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet BBB.BBB.BBB.BBZ/32 brd BBB.BBB.BBB.BBZ scope global ens3:2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And I use Python 3.5.3 and Scrapy 1.4.0

Comment: I debugged and it seems the value does go correctly to twisted from scrapy, so could be a twisted bug, if it doesn't work for you. I don't have multiple outgoing addresses to test it

Comment: How do you activate debugging in twisted ?

Comment: I used pycharm to debug Scrapy and then step into twsited

Comment: I ran a test with Twisted only and it worked.. Next step, I will try with a custom downloader.